# Unable to unzip file in zip folder R unz

Tags: r, unzip, r-unz

I'm downloading zip files from the OECD PISA dataset and unzipping them using `unz`. This works on most files but breaks on the folling:

```
library(haven)
temp <- tempfile()
download.file("https://webfs.oecd.org/pisa2018/SPSS_STU_TTM.zip",temp)
dflab <- read_sav(
    unz(temp, 
        "TTM/CY07_MSU_STU_TTM.sav"))

Error in open.connection(con, "rb") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In open.connection(con, "rb") :
  cannot locate file 'TTM/CY07_MSU_STU_TTM.sav' in zip file 'C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpmMHBNz\file357c1088d5b'
```

Opening the zip file directly, you can see the folder structure is correct:

[image: 7zip output]

The code above works on a similar file from the same OECD PISA dataset:

```
library(haven)
temp <- tempfile()
download.file("https://webfs.oecd.org/pisa2018/SPSS_SCH_QQQ.zip",temp)
dflab <- read_sav(
    unz(temp, 
        "SCH/CY07_MSU_SCH_QQQ.sav"))
```

What is causing the issue with `CY07_MSU_STU_TTM.sav`??

Comment: Do you tried with ".sav" in uppercase?

Comment: yikes, that's an easy one to fix!? I'm sure I checked that, but it seems to be working. Why the OECD keeps changing the structure of their zip files, I don't know. Shall I delete the question?

Comment: Not at all. Things like that happens sometimes because Windows tends to be case insensitive but ops like unz are built with unix in mind, which tends to not.

Comment: You could also consider using `unz(temp, unzip(temp, list = TRUE)$Name[1])` which gets the first and presumably only file in the zip file.

Comment: Brilliant! I was looking for a way to do that